# Появляющееся меню на CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, меню, позиционирование

Добрый день, коллеги!
Вопрос скорее из разряда теоретических - возможно ли это сделать и возможно ли посредством только `СSS`, а не правильно ли сделано.
Допустим мы должны на сайте сделать меню, которое появляется при нажатии на кнопку "`Menu`" в правом углу экрана. Эта кнопка в position: `fixed`, чтоб при прокрутке ее всегда можно было видеть.
Основное меню тоже в `position`: `fixed`, чтоб во первых выпало из потока и не занимало место, а во вторых появлялось в любой части страницы и оно скрыто путем установки `display`: none для контейнера (хотя я сейчас понял, что в любой части оно появляться не будет, а будет только сверху, т.к. `fixed` отталкивается от окна, а не от родителя, так что тут надо подумать о позиционировании элементов).
При событии "`active`" на кнопку "Menu" оно теоретически должно было бы появиться, т.к. у контейнера меню `display`: none заменяется на `display:block`, но меню чет не появляется.
Я еще не совсем хорошо разбираюсь в этих вещах и возможно что то упускаю, а может это вообще нельзя реализовать таким образом!
Хотел бы узнать мнения более опытных коллег)

Здесь накидал нерабочий пример своих мыслей - https://jsbin.com/dimisaquqa/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Ну не через :active, а с помощью состояния стилизованного чекбокса можно. Сам я, конечно же, такого делать не буду. Но не вижу проблем.
Кнопка меню - чекбокс, а само меню - следующий элемент от чекбокса.
и стилизуется через КНОПКА:checked + МЕНЮ {...}

[Пример с твоим кодом](https://jsbin.com/sajahatume/edit?html,css,output)